# Is there a way to change owner and group programatically with java 6?

Tags: java, jdk6

I must find a solution for changing it from java 6.
I know that it is possible to do it with Files.nio but I should only use java 6 API.

I really don't want to use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chown xx yy");

Comment: Damned spell checker :)

Comment: Honestly, I think it can't be done.  I don't think the Java 6 API includes this kind of operation.

Comment: I suppose you can always run a shell command that does it from within Java. Like you said in the question you don't want to…